# Error with dynamic SQL query variable declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I ran the following query in SQL

```
declare @h nvarchar(max)
declare @i int
set @i =1
declare @two nvarchar(max)
select @h = 'set @two = (select word from #LocalTempTable where Idcolumn =' + cast(@i as nvarchar(max)) +')'
exec(@h)
print @two
```

I got the following error

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@two".
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Its because the scope of dynamic sql is different than the batch or proc that the variable is declared. Use sp_executeSQL instead, it accepts parameters. You're still going to have a problem referencing #LocalTempTable

Comment: Thanks Conrad. I changed the exec(@h) to exec sp_executeSQL @h. Still getting the exact same error. Did I make the right change?

Comment: Are you trying to write dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the corrected one. And here is the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e31cf/2).

```
declare @h nvarchar(max)
declare @i int
set @i =1
declare @two nvarchar(max)
select @h = 'select @to = word from #LocalTempTable where Idcolumn =' + cast(@i as nvarchar(max))
exec sp_executesql @h, N'@to nvarchar(max) output', @to=@two output
print @two
```

Comment: This was beautiful thank you, I will probably have on more question for you Consult Yarla. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, shoot the question is SO, if not me, someone else can also provide answer.-- all the best.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an issue with variable scope, `@two` inside your @h variable is not declared.

You can declare it inside of your @h variable:

```
DECLARE @h nvarchar(max)
       ,@i INT = 1
SELECT @h = 'declare @two nvarchar(max) set @two = (select ''dog' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(max)) +''')'
EXEC(@h)
```

You will have a scope issue with the #temp table still, and declaring it inside makes it unavailable outside, so not much point to it.